# Deserialization of Auto-Generated Classes

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, binaryformatter

I'm using binary serialization to save objects to a configuration file and read them back again. One of these classes has an event handler which I forgot to mark with the `NonSerializedAttribute` in previous builds, so this bit of information has already ended up in a few config files. To complicate matters, this handler is initialized with a lamda expression, which forces the compiler to automatically generate an anonymous type for it.

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, args) => { };`

The issue is that this type name changed in subsequent builds, so when the `BinaryFormatter` encounters an unknown type, it throws a `SerializationException` ("Cannot find member: <.ctor>b__1"). I can't seem to catch this exception at the right location since it occurs deep inside `mscorlib.dll`, and I've had no luck with the `SerializationBinder`.

Is there any way I can force the `BinaryFormatter` to ignore this field, or remove it from the serialized stream entirely? I should add that this class in question does not implement the ISerializable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just mark the field with the `NonSerializedAttribute`?

Comment: My understanding is that if the field was serialized in a previous version of the application, then the BinaryFormatter will always attempt to deserialize it, regardless of the NonSerializedAttribute in the present version.